# Nothing happens when using Regex in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Regex really does nothing if i run this code: 
input contains: "geeeeekdldn"

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"g(.|\n)*?n", string.Empty);
```

normally after regex the value of input is "" but i still get "geeeeekdldn" 
can someone help me please

Comment: How about making a console application and testing the regex? I say this because I have 0 regular expression knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign the output of the `Replace` to a new string:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"g(.|\n)*?n", string.Empty);
```

`Replace` doesn't update the input string - see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) - because (as Hans points out) .NET strings are immutable and cannot, therefore, be changed. So any method that manipulates a string must return a new string rather than updating the supplied string.

Answer (score 2):

`Regex.Replace` is a **function** which has the string with the replacement made as its **return value**. At the moment you are discarding this return value. You probably want

```
string processedInput = Regex.Replace(input, @"g(.|\n)*?n", string.Empty);
```

Comment: what does this: @"g(.|\n)*?n" mean?

Comment: @Massimo that's a regex that (approximately) will match: a `g`, followed by one or more characters (including a newline), but matching as few as possible, followed by a `n`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the (correct) answers: the String type in .Net is immutable, meaning that a string value can only be replaced, not changed. So all functions that work on a string *always* return a new one instead of changing the argument.